# Regain access to a Slack workspace after losing access to both password, 2FA app and recovery codes

Tags: slack

I have lost access to a few Slack workspaces that I am a part of.

I accidentally deleted the login information for some of the Slack workspaces I am a part of from my password manager (1Password). The password manager also has an authentication app that generates the 2FA codes. I also store the recovery codes in the same password manager app. So in summary, I completely lost access to any means to recover my Slack workspaces.

I was able to obtain a list of all the workspaces I am a part of by going to the following URL:

- https://slack.com/get-started#/find

and entering my email.

I now have no way to login, except having access to my email address, which I can use to verify my identity and regain access to the workspaces.

**Question**:

To regain access, I tried by visiting the workspace URL and clicking the Forgot Password link. Doing so sent me a link to reset password. Clicking the link asks me to set a new password, but also asks me to enter my 2FA code, or I have lost access to that too, one of the recovery codes. However, I have neither.

[image]

Now, clicking on the [Having trouble finding your verification code?](https://slack.com/help/articles/204509068) takes me to **Set up two-factor authentication** article on Slack Help Centre page. Since I do not have access to either 2FA or recovery code, I check the Locked out? section, which points me to [ask a workspace owner or admin](https://my.slack.com/account/workspace-settings#admins)

[image]

However, clicking the link takes me to the login screen, which again asks for information which I do not have access to.

It seems I am stuck in a vicious circle.

**How do I approach regaining access to my Slack workspace(s)?**

I have access to the email address I used to register accounts. I can verify my identity via email address.

Containing Slack support team has been no help as I have done so numerous times without getting any reply.